# Mysql - Selecting rows that dont match a date range?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql that holds a start and end date field. What I need to do is query this table to find all rows that do not match the date Im searching by. How would I do that? So if I used todays date and queried this table with it then I need to find all rows that this date does not fall between the start and end date in the table. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select *
from table
where [todaysdate]<datestart
or [todaysdate]>dateend
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `BETWEEN` clause to filter records based on date range and to exclude that date range you can use `NOT` clause as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE search_date NOT BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

To select range you normally use `BETWEEN`, and if you want to exclude those values, you can simply use `NOT BETWEEN`.

Answer (score 0):

One more variant:

```
select id, start_date, end_date 
from my_table 
where end_date < CAST('2012-01-01' AS DATE) 
or start_date > CAST('2012-12-31' AS DATE)
```